# How do I connect a splash screen with main window. I created both separately

Tags: qt, qml, splash-screen

Here's the code for the splash screen.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15
import "components"
import QtQuick.Timeline 1.0

Window {
id: splashScreen
width: 380
height: 580
visible: true
color: "#00000000"
title: qsTr("Hello World")

// Remove Title Bar
flags: Qt.SplashScreen | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

Rectangle {
    id: bg
    x: 42
    y: 156
    width: 360
    height: 560
    color: "#151515"
    radius: 10
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    z: 1

    CircularProgessBar{
        id: circularProgessBar
        x: 55
        y: 197
        opacity: 1
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        value: 100
        progressWidth: 8
        strokeBgWidth: 4
        progressColor: "#67aa25"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

    }

    Image {
        id: logoImage
        x: 130
        width: 300
        height: 120
        opacity: 1
        anchors.top: parent.top
        source: "../images/351-3519717_well-pharmacy-logo.png"
        anchors.topMargin: 25
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

    }
    CustomTextField{
        id: textUsername
        x: 30
        y: 370
        opacity: 1
        anchors.bottom: textPassword.top
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 0
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        placeholderText: "Username or Email"

    }

    CustomTextField {
        id: textPassword
        x: 30
        y: 422
        opacity: 1
        anchors.bottom: btnLogin.top
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        placeholderText: "Password"
        echoMode: TextInput.Password // responsible for hiding passwords
    }

    CustomButton{
        id: btnLogin
        x: 80
        y: 473
        width: 300
        opacity: 1
        text: "Sign In"
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        font.pointSize: 10
        colorPressed: "#558b1f"
        colorMouseOver: "#7ece2d"
        colorDefault: "#67aa25"
        anchors.bottomMargin: 50
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onClicked: internal.checkLogin(textUsername.text, textPassword.text)

    }

    Label {
        id: label
        x: 111
        y: 293
        opacity: 1
        color: "#e0ebf7"
        text: qsTr("Sign In To Silk Pharma")
        anchors.bottom: label1.top
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 1
        font.family: "Segoe UI"
        font.pointSize: 16
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }

    Label {
        id: label1
        x: 56
        y: 329
        opacity: 1
        color: "#e0ebf7"
        text: qsTr("Username or Email Address and Password")
        anchors.bottom: textUsername.top
        anchors.bottomMargin: 20
        font.pointSize: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 1
        font.family: "Segoe UI"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }

    CustomButton {
        id: btnClose
        x: 328
        width: 30
        height: 30
        opacity: 1
        text: "X"
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.rightMargin: 2
        anchors.topMargin: 4
        font.pointSize: 10
        colorDefault: "#67aa25"
        colorPressed: "#558b1f"
        colorMouseOver: "#7ece2d"
        onClicked: splashScreen.close()
    }
}

DropShadow{
    anchors.fill: bg
    source: bg
    verticalOffset: 0
    horizontalOffset: 0
    radius: 10
    color: "#40000000"
    z: 0
}

Timeline {
    id: timeline
    animations: [
        TimelineAnimation {
            id: timelineAnimation
            duration: 3000
            running: true
            loops: 1
            to: 3000
            from: 0
        }
    ]
    startFrame: 0
    enabled: true
    endFrame: 3000

    KeyframeGroup {
        target: circularProgessBar
        property: "value"
        Keyframe {
            value: 0
            frame: 0
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: 100
            frame: 1300
        }
    }

    KeyframeGroup {
        target: circularProgessBar
        property: "opacity"
        Keyframe {
            value: 0
            frame: 1299
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: 0
            frame: 1798
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: "1"
            frame: 0
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: "1"
            frame: 1293
        }
    }

    KeyframeGroup {
        target: logoImage
        property: "opacity"
        Keyframe {
            value: 0
            frame: 1798
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: 1
            frame: 2303
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: "0"
            frame: 0
        }
    }

    KeyframeGroup {
        target: label
        property: "opacity"
        Keyframe {
            value: 0
            frame: 1896
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: 1
            frame: 2396
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: "0"
            frame: 0
        }
    }

    KeyframeGroup {
        target: label1
        property: "opacity"
        Keyframe {
            value: 0
            frame: 1995
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: 1
            frame: 2504
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: "0"
            frame: 0
        }
    }

    KeyframeGroup {
        target: textUsername
        property: "opacity"
        Keyframe {
            value: 0
            frame: 2099
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: 1
            frame: 2652
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: "0"
            frame: 0
        }
    }

    KeyframeGroup {
        target: textPassword
        property: "opacity"
        Keyframe {
            value: 0
            frame: 2198
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: 1
            frame: 2796
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: "0"
            frame: 0
        }
    }

    KeyframeGroup {
        target: btnLogin
        property: "opacity"
        Keyframe {
            value: 0
            frame: 2296
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: 1
            frame: 2951
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: "0"
            frame: 0
        }
    }

    KeyframeGroup {
        target: bg
        property: "height"
        Keyframe {
            value: 360
            frame: 1299
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: 560
            frame: 1900
        }

        Keyframe {
            value: "360"
            frame: 0
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here's the code for the main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import "controls"
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15

Window {
id: mainWindow
width: 1000
height: 580
visible: true
color: "#00000000"

// Remove title bar
flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint   // our window will be of type window

// Properties
property int windowStatus: 0
property int windowMargin: 10

// Internal Functions
QtObject{
    id: internal

    function maximizeRestore(){
        if(windowStatus == 0){
            mainWindow.showMaximized()
            windowStatus = 1
            windowMargin = 0
            btnMaximizeRestore.btnIconSource = "../images/svg_images/restore_icon.svg"
        }
        else{
            windowStatus = 0
            mainWindow.showNormal()
            windowMargin = 10
            btnMaximizeRestore.btnIconSource = "../images/svg_images/maximize_icon.svg"
        }
    }

    function ifMaximizedWindowRestore(){
        if(windowStatus == 1){
            mainWindow.showNormal()
            windowStatus = 0
            windowMargin = 10
            btnMaximizeRestore.btnIconSource = "../images/svg_images/maximize_icon.svg"

        }
    }

    function restoreMargins(){
        windowStatus = 0
        windowMargin = 10
        btnMaximizeRestore.btnIconSource = "../images/svg_images/maximize_icon.svg"

    }
}

title: qsTr("Course Qt Quick")

Rectangle {
    id: bg
    color: "#2c313c"
    border.color: "#383e4c"
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    anchors.rightMargin: windowMargin
    anchors.leftMargin: windowMargin
    anchors.bottomMargin: windowMargin
    anchors.topMargin: windowMargin
    z: 1

    Rectangle {
        id: appContainer
        color: "#00000000"
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.rightMargin: 1
        anchors.leftMargin: 1
        anchors.bottomMargin: 1
        anchors.topMargin: 1

        Rectangle {
            id: topBar
            height: 60
            color: "#1c1d20"
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0

            ToggleButton {
                onClicked: animationMenu.running = true
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: topBarDescription
                y: 22
                height: 25
                color: "#282c34"
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.rightMargin: 0
                anchors.leftMargin: 70
                anchors.bottomMargin: 0

                Label {
                    id: labelTopInfo
                    color: "#5f6a82"
                    text: qsTr("Application Description")
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    anchors.bottomMargin: 0
                    anchors.rightMargin: 300
                    anchors.leftMargin: 10
                    anchors.topMargin: 0
                }

                Label {
                    id: labelRightInfo
                    color: "#5f6a82"
                    text: qsTr("| HOME")
                    anchors.left: labelTopInfo.right
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    anchors.rightMargin: 10
                    anchors.leftMargin: 0
                    anchors.bottomMargin: 0
                    anchors.topMargin: 0
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: titleBar
                height: 35
                color: "#00000000"
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.rightMargin: 105
                anchors.leftMargin: 70
                anchors.topMargin: 0

                DragHandler{
                    onActiveChanged: if(active){
                                        mainWindow.startSystemMove()
                                        internal.ifMaximizedWindowRestore()
                                     }
                }

                Image {
                    id: iconApp
                    width: 22
                    height: 22
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    source: "../images/svg_images/icon_app_top.svg"
                    anchors.leftMargin: 5
                    anchors.bottomMargin: 0
                    anchors.topMargin: 0
                    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                }

                Label {
                    id: label
                    color: "#c3cbdd"
                    text: qsTr("My Application Title")
                    anchors.left: iconApp.right
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    font.pointSize: 12
                    anchors.leftMargin: 5
                }
            }

            Row {
                id: rowBtns
                x: 873
                width: 105
                height: 35
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.rightMargin: 0
                anchors.topMargin: 0

                TopBarButton {
                    id: btnMinimize
                    onClicked: {
                        mainWindow.showMinimized()
                        internal.restoreMargins()
                    }
                }

                TopBarButton {
                    id: btnMaximizeRestore
                    btnIconSource: "../images/svg_images/maximize_icon.svg"
                    onClicked: internal.maximizeRestore()

                }

                TopBarButton {
                    id: btnClose
                    btnColorClicked: "#e31d0b"
                    btnIconSource: "../images/svg_images/close_icon.svg"
                    onClicked: mainWindow.close()
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: content
            color: "#00000000"
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: topBar.bottom
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 0

            Rectangle {
                id: leftMenu
                width: 70
                color: "#1c1d20"
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                clip: false
                anchors.topMargin: 0
                anchors.bottomMargin: 0
                anchors.leftMargin: 0

                PropertyAnimation{
                    id: animationMenu
                    target: leftMenu
                    property: "width"
                    to: if(leftMenu.width == 70) return 200; else return 70
                    duration: 750
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuint
                }

                Column {
                    id: columnMenus
                    width: 70
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    anchors.rightMargin: 0
                    anchors.leftMargin: 0
                    anchors.bottomMargin: 0
                    anchors.topMargin: 0

                    LeftMenuBtn {
                        id: btnHome
                        width: leftMenu.width
                        text: qsTr("Home")
                        isActiveMenu: true
                    }

                    LeftMenuBtn {
                        id: btnHome1
                        width: leftMenu.width
                        text: qsTr("Dashboard")
                        isActiveMenu: false
                        btnIconSource: "../images/svg_images/open_icon.svg"
                    }

                    LeftMenuBtn {
                        id: btnHome2
                        width: leftMenu.width
                        text: qsTr("Search")
                        isActiveMenu: false
                        btnIconSource: "../images/svg_images/save_icon.svg"
                    }
                }

                LeftMenuBtn {
                    id: btnHome3
                    width: leftMenu.width
                    text: qsTr("Settings")
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    anchors.bottomMargin: 25
                    isActiveMenu: false
                    btnIconSource: "../images/svg_images/settings_icon.svg"
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: contentPages
                color: "#2c313c"
                anchors.left: leftMenu.right
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.rightMargin: 0
                anchors.leftMargin: 0
                anchors.bottomMargin: 25
                anchors.topMargin: 0
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: rectangle
                color: "#282c34"
                anchors.left: leftMenu.right
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: contentPages.bottom
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.rightMargin: 0
                anchors.leftMargin: 70
                anchors.bottomMargin: 25
                anchors.topMargin: 500

                Label {
                    id: labelTopInfo2
                    x: 10
                    height: 0
                    color: "#5f6a82"
                    text: qsTr("Application Description")
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    anchors.bottomMargin: 0
                    anchors.topMargin: 0
                    anchors.rightMargin: 30
                    anchors.leftMargin: 10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

DropShadow{
    anchors.fill: bg
    horizontalOffset: 0
    verticalOffset: 0
    radius: 10
    samples: 16
    color: "#80000000"
    source: bg
    z: 0
}
}
```

I want the splash screen to display first ask for login and password and then the main.qml file should appear, I tried to create a qtobject that asks the user for specific username and password and then opens the main.qml file but the main.qml file appears, the only problem is that nothing shows in the splash screen, just an empty window.

Comment: Can you show the code that loads the splash screen/main.qml?

Comment: As a side note, you should get rid of all of your `x` and `y` property settings. They're redundant since you're using anchors to position your objects.

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered the same question but since the code I've posted a bit outdated I will repost it here. The sample is a simple splash screen realization using Loader:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Loader {
    id: loader
    sourceComponent: splash
    active: true
    visible: true
    onStatusChanged: {
        if (loader.status === Loader.Ready)
        {
            item.show();
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: splash
        Window {
            id: splashWindow
            width: 300
            height: 200
            modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
            flags: Qt.SplashScreen
            color: "#DEDEDE"
            ProgressBar {
                id: progress
                anchors {
                    left: parent.left
                    right: parent.right
                    bottom: parent.bottom
                }
                value: 0
                to : 100
                from : 0
            }
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Loading,  please wait ..."
            }

            Timer {
                id: timer
                interval: 50
                running: true
                repeat: true
                onTriggered: {
                    progress.value++;
                    if(progress.value >= 100)
                    {
                        timer.stop();
                        loader.sourceComponent = undefined;
                        loader.sourceComponent = root;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: root
        Window {
            id: rootWindow
            title: "Main window"
            visible: true
            width: 800
            height: 600
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever solution. If I use a Video as my splash screen, is there a way to connect its ending with your ProgressBar? I don't think the stopped() signal will do it.